# How to include JSON webtoken in all my request query string

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, jwt

I have just learnt how to use JSON webtoken. I have been able to generate a JSON webtoken at sign-in and also setup the middleware to verify my token and protect the routes that falls below the JSON verification middleware.

Each time I try to visit my protected routes, I manually include the token by adding: `?token=gwt3r7r....` to the end of my GET requests.
I know that this should not be the case in a real app. I want this to be done dynamically.

How can this be done dynamically?

Comment: **Tip:** dont use query parameter for sending token, instead use http headers, like `Authorization: <token>`

Comment: how are you making the request to the server.?

Comment: Yes, i am making the request to the server.

Comment: I am asking `how`, are you just testing with postman, or making request using jquery ajax or some other npm package like `axios`, `fetch`, `request`, `http` or something else?

Comment: Sorry for the misconception. I am sending http request from my web browser. The  web browser is connected to my local server. I also have postman installed and connected to my local server. I test using the two

Comment: so you want to automate this `token setting task` while testing in postman or browser?

Comment: Exactly. That is what i am up to

Comment: please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, adding jwt token at the end of url is not good practice. You should pass it as headers .

What you can do is , you can pass it as `Authorization` header and on the node js side you can get it,if you ipmlement the following line:

`var token = req.headers['Authorization']`

Answer (score 0):

**Tip:** don't use query parameter for sending token, instead you should use the HTTP headers for this task.

From the front end application which is consuming your nodejs api, you can make request to your server using packages like [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios).

and when the user is successfully logged you can use

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token;
```

to set the default token for every future request, you make using this package.

## Update #1

In postman, you can save your request for future use along with token just by pressing `ctrl + s`. For headers, they have `Header presets`.

> You can save commonly used headers together in a header preset. Under the Headers tab, you can add a header preset to your request by selecting “Manage Presets” from the Presets dropdown on the right.

You can refer to [this link](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/requests) for further understanding on exactly how to use postman to its full potential.

Answer (score 0):

Put token in URL is not a good practice.

Put token as `Authorization` header is better, but it would be tedious if such header has to be assembled everytime before HTTP request is sent. Further more, this solution only works for Ajax request, it does not work when new URL/Page is visited (page protection) -- What will happen if user visit `/secure/my-account` page manually? There is no chance to define request header before page redirection.

To include jwt token in all your HTTP requests automatically, you can put it as Cookie when login is successful:

```
res.cookie('token', newToken);
```

In this way, the `token` Cookie is stored in browser through `Set-Cookie` response header, and will be sent to server automatically.

In server, to get token from each HTTP request, the following function can be used:

```
var getTokenFromRequest = function(req) {
  if (req.cookies.token) {
    return req.cookies.token;
  }
  return null;
};
```